# How can a question have 0 views and non-zero votes?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today in the Top Questions happened that a question (of mine) had 2 votes, 0 answers and 0 views. Why 0 views? Shouldn't it be at least 2? Perhaps there is something to be fixed.

Update: just now it has 5 views. Likely there is some delay on how these numbers appear in the Top Questions Page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your guess is correct. In the system, views are considered "less important" and do not get updated immediately every time some person views the question, in order to reduce strain on the servers.
Things like up/down votes, close votes, etc, are more important, and will get updated immediately. This can lead to strange situations like the one you describe.

See [Jeff Atwood's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43751/a-bug-in-the-views-calculation-views-0-time/43752#43752) to a similar question on meta.stackoverflow.